# When account is active, only Admins can edit certain fields

Tags: configuration, admin

It seems a like a simple requirement which seems like can be done using Validation Rule? However, I don't want go and do this check on all fields. So, clearly that is not a proper solution. Should I use a OWD or Restriction rules or something else? I clearly don't want to write Apex for this.

What is the best way to do it.

Thanks,
Vishnu

Comment: Hi Vishnu,  why do you think you have to check all fields in validation rule ?    Is there any scenario if you want to allow editing of a subset of fields even if it is activated.  If not , you dont have to check all the fields.  You just have to check activated condition in validation rule

Comment: I missed mentioned that it should work only for certain fields. Let me update my question.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways this may be achieved.  Here are some options :

1. Create a different record type, normal and locked and when activated, change the record type to "locked" and control the record type visibility to sys admin only.
2. Use apex lock() / unlock() methods, with checking the option "Enable record locking and unlocking in Apex" - This can be done at the time the record is activated.

Some reactive options... (would not prefer though)
3. When an activated record is updated, create a Flow (Every time a record is edited, and for the specific condition) - prevent it from being saved.
4. Do the same with trigger

and some more... but trying to keep it simple.